# How to simulate from a complete block design equation in R?

Tags: r

I know that if I want to simulate data from a normal distribution like
Y~N(x,y<sup>2</sup>) I can use

```
Y <- rnorm(n = 30,mean = x, sd = y)
```

and similarly for other distributions.

But it is it possible to simulate values from a randomised complete block design equation like

Y<sub>xy</sub> = µ + T<sub>x</sub> + B<sub>y</sub> + E<sub>xy</sub>

where T<sub>x</sub> is treatment effect x, B<sub>y</sub> is block effect y and E<sub>xy</sub> are the residuals?

Comment: From this equation Yxy = µ + Tx + By + Exy, which values are you trying to randomise? Can you better elaborate your question?

Comment: I'm not really sure, the treatment and block effects are known and change depending on treatment and block, so I think the residuals which should be ~N(0,σ^2)

Comment: If you want to randomise something you should know what you're randomising. The residuals are not randomised but calculated from the rest of the equation. Either this is a question about statistics, meaning that this is the wrong page, or it is about randomising something in R, which in that case you need to be more specific.
If you have A = B + C + D, you have to know which are the variables you want to randomise. Otherwise nobody will be able to help you.